# Snowflake-SQL: Summing values prior to Left Join without Summarizing/Grouping Data

Tags: sql, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, left-join

I am trying to Left Join Table A with Table B on ID # to compare Costs vs Payments.  However, in this particular instance, I do not want to group or summarize the data.  I need all rows (and line level detail) from Table A without duplicating. Table B has some duplicate IDs, so I want to pull in the sum of the Payments from Table B for each row in Table A.

First I tried a simple Left Join, but this created duplicate rows in Table A.

```
Select 
A.ID, A.Part_Description, A.Part_Cost, B.Total_Payment 
From
TableA as A
Left Join TableB as B
on A.ID = B.ID
```

Which gave me this:

| A.ID | A.Part_Description | A.Part_Cost | B.Total_Payment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_1 | Part A | 3 | 1.2 |
| ID_1 | Part B | 2 | 1.2 |
| ID_1 | Part A | 3 | 3.8 |
| ID_1 | Part B | 2 | 3.8 |

I've looked into Partitioning with Row_Number functions as well, but that will give me either the most recent or largest Payment from Table B.  Grouping the data removes details from Table A that I want to keep.

Since B.ID shows up several times in Table B with different B.Payment values, I need to get the sum of B.Payments prior to the join, preventing duplicate rows from TableA in the results.

Expected Result

| A.ID | A.Part_Description | A.Part_Cost | B.Total_Payment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_1 | Part A | 3 | 5 |
| ID_1 | Part B | 2 | 5 |
| ID_2 | Part A | 3 | 12 |
| ID_2 | Part B | 2 | 12 |
| ID_2 | Part C | 7 | 12 |

I would like to use the results to compare the Costs vs Payments, so occasionally, I expect B.Total_Cost to be different than sum(A.Part_Cost) for a specific ID.

Any ideas?  I'm pretty new to SQL and joining tables... I suspect that I may need to use a subquery, but I'm struggling a bit.

Comment: can you post also the data of the original tables?

Comment: Can you give me some info on what you are looking for?  This is a simplified example.  I'm selecting ~50 of 250 columns from Table A, but only a single column (sum of payments) from Table B, which has about 30 columns.

Comment: Instead of joining to the table, join to a subquery e.g. From
TableA as A
Left Join ( select id, sum(total_payment) from TableB group by id) as B
on A.ID = B.ID

Comment: @Scotchy you have in the second result set a `id 2` that isn't in the first, so we can not understand where the values are coming from with out knowimg  table A or tabl B and their data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want only a simple `GROUP BY`

```
Select 
A.ID, A.Part_Description, MAX(A.Part_Cost), SUM(B.Total_Payment) as Total_Payment
From
TableA as A
Left Join TableB as B
on A.ID = B.ID
GROUP BY A.ID, A.Part_Description
```

Comment: Thanks.  This worked, but only after I included all of the columns in TableA in the Group By, which I didn't realize was necessary.  Usually I use Group By to summarize data for a small set of columns.  However, It seems that there is a limit, so I couldn't add all 50 columns I wanted into the Group By function.  Is there any way around this?  I am using Snowflake and received the following error before I reduced the number of columns.  "unexpected '<EOF>'. (line 314)"

Comment: all column in the select must be in the group by or have an aggregation function, so if you find a column that has always the same value simply remove from the group by and make MAX(column_name), that should remove some columns from there

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @NickW, join table A and subquery from table B.
See example:

```
create table A(ID varchar(8),Part_Description varchar(20),Part_Cost float);
create table B(ID varchar(8),Total_Payment float);
insert into A values
 ('ID_1','Part A',  3)
,('ID_1','Part B',  2)
,('ID_2','Part A',  3)
,('ID_2','Part B',  2)
,('ID_2','Part C',  7)
;
insert into B values
 ('ID_1',1.2)
,('ID_1',3.8)
,('ID_2',3.0)
,('ID_2',5.0)
,('ID_2',4.0)
;
select *  -- all columns from A
from A
left join  -- Id and 1 aggregate column from B -sum of B.Payments prior to the join
  (select ID,sum(Total_Payment)[B.Total_Payment] from B group by ID) B
   on a.ID=b.ID
```

Result

| ID | Part_Description | Part_Cost | ID | B.Total_Payment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_1 | Part A | 3 | ID_1 | 5 |
| ID_1 | Part B | 2 | ID_1 | 5 |
| ID_2 | Part A | 3 | ID_2 | 12 |
| ID_2 | Part B | 2 | ID_2 | 12 |
| ID_2 | Part C | 7 | ID_2 | 12 |

Subquery gets result

| ID | B.Total_Payment |
| --- | --- |
| ID_1 | 5 |
| ID_2 | 12 |